# TALLY XML INTEGRATION - REQUEST TYPES ETC

Tags: integration, tally

I am trying to integrate my POS system with Tally. Where can I find all the Request Type etc available for integration. Is there a documentation available ?

Answer (score 2):

The Tally XML structure is as follows :

**To Import data into Tally**

```
<ENVELOPE>
  <HEADER>
    <TALLYREQUEST>Import Data</TALLYREQUEST>
  </HEADER>
  <BODY>
    <IMPORTDATA>
      <REQUESTDESC>
        <REPORTNAME>All Masters</REPORTNAME>
      </REQUESTDESC>
      <REQUESTDATA>
        <TALLYMESSAGE xmlns:UDF="TallyUDF">
          <!-- Your data goes here -->
        </TALLYMESSAGE>
      </REQUESTDATA>
    </IMPORTDATA>
  </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

Remarks:
As you can see, the data to be pushed into Tally has to be written in the `TALLYMESSAGE` tag.

**To Export data from Tally**

```
<ENVELOPE>  
  <HEADER>  
    <TALLYREQUEST>Export Data</TALLYREQUEST>  
  </HEADER>  
  <BODY>  
    <EXPORTDATA>  
      <REQUESTDESC>  
        <!-- Specify the Report Name here -->  
        <REPORTNAME>List of Accounts</REPORTNAME>  
        <STATICVARIABLES>  
          <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>  
        </STATICVARIABLES>  
      </REQUESTDESC>  
    </EXPORTDATA>  
  </BODY>  
</ENVELOPE>
```

Remarks:
The report or data to be retrieved from Tally is to be given in the `REPORTNAME` tag.

There are many reports in Tally ERP 9. The XML tags to retrieve / export data from Tally are given here :
https://www.rtslink.com/articles/tally-xml-tags-export/

Similarly XML tags to Import data into Tally are given here
https://www.rtslink.com/articles/tally-xml-tags-import/

Hope the above resources helps those who wish to integrate with Tally.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

As per the [reference guide](http://mirror.tallysolutions.com/tallyweb/tally/td9/Tally.ERP9_Integration_Capabilities.pdf), there are 3 types of requests:

1. Export
2. Import
3. Execute

You can use any of these within the 'TALLYREQUEST' xml tag. Of course, there's a lot more information you'd have to put in to create a complete XML request, and all the details are in the guide. For example, the following exports a list of all masters from Tally:

```
<ENVELOPE>
    <HEADER>
        <VERSION>1</VERSION>
        <TALLYREQUEST>EXPORT</TALLYREQUEST>
        <TYPE>DATA</TYPE>
        <ID>All masters</ID>
    </HEADER>
    <BODY>
        <DESC>
        </DESC>
    </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```